# Naming Convention in imports - use \class vs use class

Tags: magento2, naming-convention

I found that, "Magento 2, At its core is PSR-4 compliant".

Then I got into this: 
https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

and the table at the bottom:

```
FULLY QUALIFIED CLASS NAME -> \Acme\Log\Writer\File_Writer
```

So I see from the most of Magento2 Code cases, that it uses:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
```

shouldn't it be like :

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
```

when it points to a class ?

and then when it comes to Constructors in Magento2 I can clearly see that this kind of syntax is used:

```
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
```

Is used

mb I'm missing some core fundamentals but I'm curious about it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `\` (backslash) represents the global namespace (root scope) in the starting of a namespace.
  [`check: What does a \ (backslash) do in PHP (5.3+)?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4790031/5962966)
- `use` is a way of using a class, function, const in another class.
  All `use` namespaces are not processed relative to the current
  namespace but to global namespace, so adding a preceeding `\` is
  unecessary and invalid. [check:  Using namespaces:
  Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Thx, this makes this topic clear for me.